# "a shortest path" vs "the shortest path"

Tags: articles

**First, note that there are many such paths.**

The distance between two vertices u and v of a graph G is the number of
edges in a shortest path connecting them.

or

The distance between two vertices u and v of a graph G is the number of
edges in the shortest path connecting them.

Comment: While there can be many paths, in most cases there is only one _shortest_ path.

Comment: KillingTime: This is not true.

Comment: In that case it's _the_ shortest path.

Comment: Are there any situations with -est and a/an?

Comment: This implies that there is a largest integer i.

Comment: Consider when there is more than one equal shortest path: "G is the number of edges in each/every shortest path."

Comment: If "the shortest path" is uncomfortable because there is no unique shortest path, but there is at least one, then you have to use "a" instead of "the".

Comment: @ZYX: Who wrote the sentence?  In "a shortest path" "shortest path" seems to be a compound noun given to a phenomenon in mathematics. A/An [noun]  = One example of a [noun]